# Python: how to merge two dataframe based only on different columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2`

```
df1
     A  B
0    4  2
1    3  3
2    1  2

df2
     B  AB C
0    4  8  3
1    3  9  2
2    1  2  4
```

I would like to make a join only on different columns

```
df3
     A  B  AB  C
0    4  2  8   3
1    3  3  9   2
2    1  2  2   4
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html) with inverse mask or [`Index.difference`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html):

```
df22 = df2.loc[:, ~df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)]
df = df1.join(df22)
```

Or:

```
df22 = df2[df2.columns.difference(df1.columns)]
df = df1.join(df22)
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  AB  C
0  4  2   8  3
1  3  3   9  2
2  1  2   2  4
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the merge functions as an alternate solution:

```
df3=pd.merge(df1,df2, left_on='A', right_on='B', how ='left', suffixes=('','_')).drop('B_',axis=1)
```